# Easiest way to find Unique object from a list of object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In my project, I have two entities first one is the `Business entity(BE)` which is coming from a client (or) customer and another one is `Data Entity(DE)` which is from the database.

**GoodsReceipt.cs**

```
public class GoodsReceipt
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GoodsReceiptProduct> GoodsReceiptProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

**GoodsReceiptProduct.cs**

```
public class GoodsReceiptProduct
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid GoodsReceiptId { get; set; }
        public Guid PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    }
```

My requirement is to get whether a new item is `added` or `updated` or `deleted` in the `GoodsReceiptProducts` collection. And the `PurchaseOrderId` in GoodsReceiptProduct is a unique one for all the object in the list.

The user will send the `BE` `GoodsReceipt` along with a collection of `GoodsReceiptProduct`. So what are the possible ways to get that **unique object** from the list which may get added or updated or deleted on comparing that list with an existing `DE` list on the server.

Comment: What is criteria for deciding that the object is unique?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari PurchaseOrderId is criteria for deciding that the object is unique.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari . What is want to achieve is in single PUT request i want to find out whether an item is added or deleted in that GoodsReceiptProducts collection

Comment: Why dont you maintain Dictionary<Guid, GoodsRecipeProduct>.   Always insert purchaseorderid as key.  That way you can check if key is already existing.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari. Ya, I can do that. But my current objective is to pick that new one from the collection by using BE and DE only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to compare 2 lists and Identify Which records are newly added, or deleted, or remaining as it is. Instead of finding a unique object.

For this, you can use **Except & Intersect**

For Example:

```
List<GoodsReceiptProduct> existingListInDataEntity = GetExistingList();
List<GoodsReceiptProduct> modifiedListInBusinessEntity = GetBusinessList();

var newAddedItems = modifiedListInBusinessEntity.Except(existingListInDataEntity);
var deletedItems = existingListInDataEntity.Except(modifiedListInBusinessEntity);
var sameItems = modifiedListInBusinessEntity.Intersect(existingListInDataEntity);
```

Comment: @Nilay.This is want exactly i want. but i am getting this error => 'List<GoodsReceiptProduct>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Except<GoodsReceiptProduct>(ParallelQuery<GoodsReceiptProduct>, IEnumerable<GoodsReceiptProduct>)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<GoodsReceiptProduct>'

Comment: Got the error because of MisMatch between DE and BE. Thanks a lot for your information.

Comment: You need to include `System.Linq` namespace. If both models are a different kind then you can obtain `List<Guid>` first and then compare that Guids

Answer (score -1):

Use `Distinct()` in IEnumerables

Eg:

```
var YourList = List<GoodsReceiptProduct>();

//YourList = propulate the list here;

var UniqueList = YourList.Distinct();
```

Comment: What is more than one item added? Does Distinct return those newly added items?

Comment: Distinct always returns all items that are distinct that. You can also use the package `MoreLinq` to use `DistinctBy` to decide what key should be used to decide if something is distinct or not

Comment: @BaskaranS Distinct will return "Distinct" List Items of your list (Whatever items exists at the time of executing the Distinct Method).